# Plotting inside a loop gives me empty plots

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart

I got this CSV:

[image]

and this code:

```
import csv
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

filename = '../dataset/data_validation/annotationValidation.csv'
fields = ['Image', 'Color', 'Validator']
imageIds = ['photo-1612694875299-4c379cb55ae2.jpg', 'photo-1611308382871-971045fcff4e.jpg', 'photo-1621329564823-1e0555fea622.jpg', 'photo-1624828002048-2681f0e67aed.jpg']


with open(filename, 'r') as csv_file:
    dict_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file)
    headers = dict_reader.fieldnames
    for imageId in imageIds:
        # Color
        blackAndWhite, colorful = 0, 0
        count = 0
        for row in dict_reader:
            count = count + 1
            print(count)
            if imageId == row['Image']:
                print(imageId)
                # Color
                if (row['Color']) == 'Black & White':
                    blackAndWhite = blackAndWhite + 1
                else:
                    colorful = colorful + 1
        labels = ['Black & White', 'Colorful']
        counts = np.array([blackAndWhite, colorful])
        # creating the bar plot
        plt.barh(labels, counts, color='maroon')
        plt.xlabel("No of Answers")
        plt.ylabel("Labels")
        plt.title("Metrics")
        plt.ioff()
        plt.show()
```

and I am trying to plot a bar for each image I find on my csv. In this example I have 3 images on my imageIds array, so 3 plots in total, showing the distribution between colorful and b&w.

The thing is, only my first plot appears, all the others are coming empty.
I am not sure if it something with my 2 loops or a matplotlib related thing.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Ok found the error. I need to open csv before the second loop, meaning reopening csv from the start, cause probably once all the lines are read then the csv closes. Thank you all